# Android & RoboGuice - Property injection inside a service?

Tags: android, intentservice, roboguice

I have an intent service, and I need to inject properties in this class. Right now RoboGuice doesn't inject them, and the properties are always null.

My workaround is to have 2 static variables on my IntentService, and on Application load I get the instances from RobogGuice and I set these static variables manually.

Is there a better way to handle this, and be able to handle injection inside the service itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to Inherit form `RoboIntentService` instead of `IntentService`, and that solved the injection problem.